# Add to byte array in VB.net

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, byte

How to write this code in VB.NET??

```
byte[] bArr = new byte[2] { 0x1B, 0x68 };
```

I tried all I know and search around, but couldn't find right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim bArr As Byte() = New Byte(1) {&H1B, &H68}
```

You can use http://converter.telerik.com/ in future.

Comment: Or less verbose: Dim bArr() As Byte = { &H1B, &H68 }

Answer (score 1):

[dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) is a good resource for testing and converting code between C# and VB.Net

```
Dim bArr As Byte() = New Byte(1) {27, 104}
```